# Printing the smallest element of an array and linking

Tags: java, arrays

Um, hi. So, I've been doing well with my beginner programing stuff until I came to one part concerning arrays and I am really stuck. I got a task to make two arrays, one with names and another one with money and I have to make a program which prints out the smallest amount of money (smallest array element) and the person who that money belongs to. I've tried to link them using a method I use when I sort from smallest to the biggest but here it doesn't work and it prints out the wrong thing.

```
package questions;
public class Questions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[]Names = {"Person","Human","Being"};
        int[]Money = {56,23,76};

            int minValue = Money[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < Money.length; i++) {

                if (Money[i] < minValue) {
                    minValue = Money[i];

                }

                System.out.println ("The person with least amount of money is: " + minValue + "  "+ Names[i]);


            }
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what do I have to do to make it only print out:

```
The person with least amount of money is: 23 Human
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a variable that will contain the min money index and print after the for loop:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[]Names = {"Person","Human","Being"};
        int[]Money = {56,23,76};

        int minValue = Money[0];
        int minIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Money.length; i++) {

            if (Money[i] < minValue) {
                minValue = Money[i];
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println ("The person with least amount of money is: " + Money[minIndex] + "  "+ Names[minIndex]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write print line out of loop Like:-

```
public class Questions
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[]Names = {"Person","Human","Being"};
        int[]Money = {56,23,76};
        //Name having least money
        String namewithleatmoney = "";  
        int minValue = Money[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < Money.length; i++)
        {
            if (Money[i] < minValue)
            {
               minValue = Money[i];
               namewithleatmoney = Names[i];
           }
        }
        //Write this line out of loop
        System.out.println ("The person with least amount of money is: " + minValue + "  "+namewithleatmoney);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple. you just need to track the index number on the smallest amount of the money from the array. See the code below you will understand. I have just saved the index of the smallest amount index in ** minValuIndex ** and in the end of the for loop I just printed the values depending on the index number.

```
package questions;
public class Questions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[]Names = {"Person","Human","Being"};
        int[]Money = {56,23,76};

            int minValue = Money[0];
            int minValuIndex = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < Money.length; i++) {

                if (Money[i] < minValue) {
                    minValue = Money[i];
                    minValuIndex = i;

                }

                System.out.println ("The person with least amount of money is: " + 
                money[minValuIndex]+ "  "+ Names[minValuIndex ]);


            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> try like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] Names = { "Person", "Human", "Being" };
        int[] Money = { 56, 23, 76 };

        int minValue = Money[0];
        String personName = Names[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < Money.length; i++) {

            if (Money[i] < minValue) {
                minValue = Money[i];
                personName= Names[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The person with least amount of money is: " + minValue + "  " + personName);
    }
```